# Blazor WASM Prerendering with SignalR - Cannot instantiate implementation type IAccessTokenProvider

Tags: signalr, blazor, webassembly

I'm trying to prerender my Blazor WASM application which has SignalR on the layout page.

I added my dependencies in the startup.cs, but when I add `services.AddScoped<IAccessTokenProvider>();` in my startup.cs file, I get the following error:

ArgumentException: Cannot instantiate implementation type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IAccessTokenProvider' for service type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IAccessTokenProvider'.

My question is how to do prerendering Blazor WASM with SignalR. Thanks.

Comment: Not answering the prerendering question as I have little experience with that and WASM, however your error with the scoped service is you have to supply the class to instantiate, not just the interface. Ex. `services.AddScoped<IAccessTokenProvider, MyAccessTokenProvider>();`

Comment: In WASM when you want to get the token for SignalR you can just inject on the razor page like this: `@inject IAccessTokenProvider tokenProvider`, and you don't need to register it inside program.cs by supplying a class (like in startup.cs of API). that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: It won't exist server-side, what are you using for authentication? Also, why prerender WASM any way? Its extremely fast as is. The slowness comes from downloading the project assets (your internet speed), not rendering the components.

Comment: The reason is not only for the speed. one of the reasons to prerender is to make it SEO friendly as crawlers won't see your content if not prerendered.